# RNfirebase installation issue with firebase-functions 11.6

Tags: react-native-firebase

I keep getting the following error when I am trying to run the build after completing all the RNFIREBASE steps to install Firebase for my react-native project.

- RN version: 0.55.3
- Using appcenter for builds

The build was working fine on appcenter when I did not add firebase. The build on iOS is working on the phone and appcenter.

### Error

```
>  - Trying to run build on Appcenter. Using configuration: release
> 
> Resolved com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.3 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.0 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
Resolved com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 in :react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath 
:react-native-firebase:compileReleaseAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:11.6.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      file:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      file:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      file:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      file:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      file:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      file:/Users/vsts/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      file:/Users/vsts/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      file:/Users/vsts/agent/2.140.0/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      file:/Users/vsts/agent/2.140.0/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
      https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.pom
      https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-functions/11.6.0/firebase-functions-11.6.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :react-native-firebase
```

### android/build.gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '11.6.0'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                    details.useVersion '11.6.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
               // buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                lintOptions { 
                    checkReleaseBuilds false
                    }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### app/build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"
apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js"
]

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        debug  : ".env",
        staging: ".env",
        release: ".env",
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    //   buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "in.app"
        applicationId "in.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.1.5"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "CODE_PUSH_KEY", '""'
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        }
        releaseStaging {
            // initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField "String", "CODE_PUSH_KEY", ''
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "CODE_PUSH_KEY", ''
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    api project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    api project(':react-native-svg')
    api project(':react-native-paytm')
    api project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    api project(':react-native-image-picker')
    api project(':react-native-google-fit')
    api project(':react-native-device-info')
    api project(':react-native-config')
    api project(':react-native-code-push')
    api project(':react-native-razorpay')
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    api 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all api dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.api
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: could you show your gradle setting from android and RNFirebase android folders

Comment: Hello, I have added the gradle files.